# How to send ews email with inline attachments for requested exchange Server Version Exchange2007_SP1

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Because Attachment.IsInline property is not supported  exchange Server Version  Exchange2007_SP1, is there way send inline attachments ?

```
string file = @"C:\Temp\Party.jpg";
    message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("Party.jpg", file);
    message.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
    message.Attachments[0].ContentId = "Party.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating a object of exchange service select any version who is above Exchange2007_sp1 like :

```
ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010); // Exchange2010_sp1, Exchange2013 etc.
```

Inline attachment for below object will not be supported if created using Exchange2007_sp1

```
ExchangeService objInlineNotSupportedExchange= new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
```